# Removing only blank cells (not rows) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Could you please assist in a simple Google Sheets script to allow me to take a sheet that looks like this:

[image: Before picture]

to automatically convert it with 1 click to this (ie - not to delete ROWS, but to delete and move up on empty cells only):

[image: After Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample as you requested:

```
function adder()
 {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
   for (var i = 1; i < lastRow+1; i++){
     if((sheet.getRange('A'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue()) + ""=="")
     {
       sheet.getRange('A'+(lastRow-i+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
     }

     //var valueB = sheet.getRange('B'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue() + "";
     if((sheet.getRange('B'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue())=="")
     {
       sheet.getRange('B'+(lastRow-i+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
     }

     //var valueC = sheet.getRange('C'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue() + "";
     if((sheet.getRange('C'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue())=="")
     {
       sheet.getRange('C'+(lastRow-i+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - but getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getLastRow" of null. (line 4).

Comment: this run in macro, but if you want to run as script, you must change the active spreadsheet

Comment: and sheet2 must be change to your actual sheet

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:C1; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A2:C,,999^99)), " "))})
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent - works well. The only problem is that I need to do it daily - would there be a macro or some quick shortcut I can use to run this formula on another sheet and then paste back as plain text on the main sheet?

Comment: Additionally, some rows actually have spaces like "1x Product A", which causes it to split into 3 rows - "1x", "Product" and "A" on separate rows

Comment: I also like this one the best, mainly because it keeps it as a cell formula.

Comment: @player0 Actually does this not work when special characters exist in the range cells? 

https://i.postimg.cc/26qf00Q5/remove-blank-cells.png

It seems to split the source cell into multiple cells.

Also what if I am only processing a single column?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? (image does not load)

Comment: @player0 Do you also have a version that allows spaces in the cells? Currently a space inside a cell will cause the cell to be split into multiple cells

Comment: @Daantje sure, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:C1; SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(A2:C, " ", "♥"),,999^99)), " ")), "♥", " ")})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
sheet.getRange('A12').deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS); // Cell left
sheet.getRange('A12').deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);  //cell up
```

or

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = sheet.getRange('A12');
range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
```

you must iterate from last row, and then check one by one of your column A, B, C or others cells from bottom, if blank then do range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);

Comment: Thanks - excuse my ignorance, but how do I get this to run now? I tried putting it in a function, but running the function does nothing. Also, not sure what your last line means? "you must iterate from last row, and then check one by one of your column A, B, C or others cells from bottom, if blank then do range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);"

Comment: I will give you sample